# Hyphen is being replaced by strange symbol

Tags: java, testng

I am testing the response body from a SOAP service. I get the response from the SOAP service and store it as String and then compare it against the expected response. I am using org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert to do the comparison. Once the comparison happens I am getting and error because a difference was found. I copied and pasted the testng error in Notepad++ to see the difference. The response is supposed to have a hyphen, so I added that to  my expected response. But for some reason in the error message I see the hyphen in the expected response being replaced with weird character.

This is my expected response(**The hyphen is on  <faultstring> and ns2:LogMessage tags**) :

```
   public String getADJUP004ExpectedResponse(){
    return
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"+
                    "   <soapenv:Header/>\n" +
                    "   <soapenv:Body>\n" +
                    "      <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n\n" +
                    "            <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>\n" +
                    "            <faultstring>Request Rejected – Old and New Adjuster Code are same on claim.</faultstring>\n" +
                    "            <detail>\n" +
                    "               <ns2:BaseFault xmlns:ns2=\"http://services.mycccportal.com/SOA/fault/v1\">\n" +
                    "                   <ns2:UserMessage>"+"004"+"</ns2:UserMessage>\n" +
                    "                   <ns2:LogMessage>Request Rejected – Old and New Adjuster Code are same on claim.</ns2:LogMessage>\n" +
                    "                   <ns2:MustUnderstandChild>true</ns2:MustUnderstandChild>\n"+
                    "                   <ns2:Level>"+"SEVERE"+"</ns2:Level>\n" +
                    "                   <ns2:UniqueTransactionId>"+uniqueTransactionID+"</ns2:UniqueTransactionId>\n" +
                    "               </ns2:BaseFault>\n" +
                    "           </detail>\n" +
                    "       </ns0:Fault>\n" +
                    "   </soapenv:Body>" +
                    "</soapenv:Envelope>";
}
```

And this is the error I am seeing from testng where the expected response hyphen has been replace with another character.

```
       InboundEventSOAPTest.tc22BusinessErrorADJUP004:626 The following asserts failed:
       Differences were found on the response body. Expected:
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Request Rejected ▒ Old and New Adjuster Code are same on claim.</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <ns2:BaseFault xmlns:ns2="http://services.mycccportal.com/SOA/fault/v1">
                <ns2:UserMessage>004</ns2:UserMessage>
                <ns2:LogMessage>Request Rejected ▒ Old and New Adjuster Code are same on claim.</ns2:LogMessage>
                <ns2:MustUnderstandChild>true</ns2:MustUnderstandChild>
                <ns2:Level>SEVERE</ns2:Level>
                <ns2:UniqueTransactionId>QOTesteqa202261516659614QOUSER</ns2:UniqueTransactionId>
            </ns2:BaseFault>
        </detail>
    </ns0:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

but found 

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Request Rejected – Old and New Adjuster Code are same on claim.</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <ns2:BaseFault xmlns:ns2="http://services.mycccportal.com/SOA/fault/v1">
                <ns2:UserMessage>004</ns2:UserMessage>
                <ns2:LogMessage>Request Rejected – Old and New Adjuster Code are same on claim.</ns2:LogMessage>
                <ns2:MustUnderstandChild>true</ns2:MustUnderstandChild>
                <ns2:Level>SEVERE</ns2:Level>
                <ns2:UniqueTransactionId>QOTesteqa202261516659614QOUSER</ns2:UniqueTransactionId>
            </ns2:BaseFault>
        </detail>
    </ns0:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually a hyphen, not one of the many other hyphen-like characters? [This is interesting](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Pd)

Comment: What character set is the SOAP service returning its response in, what character set are you expecting it to be in, and what the numerical code points of the expected and actual characters? Remember, computers only deal with numbers. The idea that 'A' is represented by the number 65 is merely a convention, and not always observed (EBCDIC). It looks like you have an encoding problem.

Comment: OK, I had a look, using [this web site](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) - which tells me that the character in your `getADJUP004ExpectedResponse` method is an en-dash, not a hyphen.  And according to TestNG, your actual output also has an en-dash, so it should be OK.  But the TestNG output shows that your expectation was for something else.  So at least part of the issue is either with TestNG, or with the way you're using TestNG.  Can you please show us some more code - like the whole TestNG test, or at the very least, the failing assertion?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem This is the assertion I am using: softAssert.assertEquals(actualResponseBody,expectedResponseBody,"Differences were found on the response body");  .  I use similar assertions for other tests and they work fine.

Comment: OK, but you can see that TestNG is reporting that your "expected response" is different from the String provided by `getADJUP004ExpectedResponse`.  So either you're doing something to it between calling `getADJUP004ExpectedResponse` and calling `softAssert.assertEquals`, or there's a bug in TestNG, or your console window is messing up the encoding.  Since you still haven't shown the code of the test, I can't give any more help.